# How to recalculate an object from a nested objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object where Citems is an array of Object. Each object has status on or of and time.

```
{
  Chapter: [
    {
      Cname: 'chapter 1',
      Citems: [{status: 'on', time: 30},{status: 'on', time: 60}],
      
    },
    {
      Cname: 'chapter 2',
      Citems: [{status: 'on', time: 30},{status: 'off', time: 60}]
    }
  ],
  name: 'Something',
  description: 'jfdgljfgdfjgldfkjglfd'
}
```

I want to generate an array or object from it that show total time for each status like below

```
{
on: 120,
off: 60
}
```

I tried with map and reduce but getting confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a nested 'sum', here implemented using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and making use of [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015) to update the accumulator using the `status` as key.

```js
const data = { Chapter: [{ Cname: 'chapter 1', Citems: [{ status: 'on', time: 30 }, { status: 'on', time: 60 }], }, { Cname: 'chapter 2', Citems: [{ status: 'on', time: 30 }, { status: 'off', time: 60 }] }], name: 'Something', description: 'jfdgljfgdfjgldfkjglfd' };

const result = data.Chapter.reduce((a, { Citems }) => {
  for (const { status, time } of Citems) {
    a[status] += time;
  }
  return a;
}, { on: 0, off: 0 });

console.log(result);
```

Or using a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop

```js
const data = { Chapter: [{ Cname: 'chapter 1', Citems: [{ status: 'on', time: 30 }, { status: 'on', time: 60 }], }, { Cname: 'chapter 2', Citems: [{ status: 'on', time: 30 }, { status: 'off', time: 60 }] }], name: 'Something', description: 'jfdgljfgdfjgldfkjglfd' }

const result = { on: 0, off: 0 };

for (const { Citems } of data.Chapter) {
  for (const { status, time } of Citems) {
    result[status] += time;
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

To extend this to an array of such `Chapter` objects you could nest it once more in a `reduce()`.

```js
const data = [
  {
    Chapter: [{ Cname: 'chapter 1', Citems: [{ status: 'on', time: 30 }, { status: 'on', time: 60 }], }, { Cname: 'chapter 2', Citems: [{ status: 'on', time: 30 }, { status: 'off', time: 60 }] }],
    name: 'Something',
    description: 'jfdgljfgdfjgldfkjglfd'
  },
  {
    Chapter: [{ Cname: 'chapter 1', Citems: [{ status: 'on', time: 30 }, { status: 'off', time: 30 }], }, { Cname: 'chapter 2', Citems: [{ status: 'on', time: 30 }, { status: 'off', time: 60 }] }],
    name: 'Something2',
    description: 'asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfa'
  }
]

const result = data.reduce((a, { name, Chapter }) => {
  a[name] = Chapter.reduce((a, { Citems }) => {
    for (const { status, time } of Citems) {
      a[status] += time;
    }
    return a;
  }, { on: 0, off: 0 });

  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let obj = {Chapter: [{_id: '624568b157da1d351910c576',Cname:'chapter 1',Citems: [{status: 'on',time: 30},{status: 'on',time: 60}],},{_id:'456a5857da1d351910c577',Cname: 'chapter 2',Citems: [{status:'on',time: 30},{status: 'off',time: 60}]}],_id: '6245f975d17514e0eb9092f7',name:'Something',description:'fdgljfgdfjgldfkjglfd'}
console.log(function() {
  let on=0, off=0; //define return variables (if there is not 'on' or 'off' element at the object, the amount is 0)
  obj['Chapter'].forEach(function(elem) {
    if (elem['Citems']) { //if the list item of 'Chapter' does not have a 'Citems' attribute, we will not deal with it
      elem['Citems'].forEach(function(e) {
        if (e['status'] == 'on') {on += e['time']} else if (e['status'] == 'off') {off += e['time']}
      })
    }
  });
  return {
    on: on,
    off: off
  }
}())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).